# 64-bit C++ Eclipse Is Making a 32-bit Executables

Tags: c++, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

When I run my program, which I wrote in a 64-bit Eclipse, I get a 32-bit executable. When I first opened Eclipse it asked for a kernel32.lib. Does this force Eclipse to make 32-bit applications?

## Q. Is there a way to tell it to use the 64-bit kernel? Or an option to make Eclipse compile 64-bit programs?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://pinyotae.blogspot.nl/2010/05/eclipse-mingw-x64.html i don't know what compiler you are using, but this should be similar for other compilers

Answer (score 2):

"Bit-ness" of Eclipse has nothing to do with the executable it will produce - that depends entirely on the compiler you use or the flags passed to the compiler. You can produce 32-bit executables in 64-bit Eclipse or 64-bit executables in 32-bit Eclipse (as well as 32->32 and 64->64).

Comment: ok, when I created a new project I selected a Toolchain with a 32bit compiler. So I guess that I have to download a 64bits compiler (or toolchain?), right?

Comment: @Anxious - Well, to add to confusion, there are 32-bit compilers targeting 64-bit environments - after all that's a typical cross-compilation (; But generally yes - you need to have a toolchain that is able to produce 64-bit executables (toolchain executables can be 32-bits). For PC environment and GCC, you should look for something with x86_64-... in the name, i686-... (and similar) target 32-bits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Eclipse to compile 64-bit.

To do this go to the "Compiler/Linker" Settings Configuration page: It should be under: "GCC C Linker > Miscellaneous". Under "Linker Flags" add:

> -m64

Comment: doesn't work for me, in the windows task manager I still see it running as 32 bits.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks You can see here that *if* you are using gcc as your compiler and *if* you use the "-m64" flag you can see that you should generate code for a 64-bit environment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html

Comment: The issue was that my old minGW version didn't support 64 bit. I upgraded minGW to x86_64 and then it worked.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Thanks for responding back. Hopefully that'll be helpful to someone else.